# I would like to create generic method to verify sort list with default list to save time during testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I created a method to fulfill my requirement as below:

1. Select Sort By position "Name: Z to A"
2. Verify the Product will arrange in Descending order(with product name descending) BaseUrl I used is: https://demo.nopcommerce.com/

```java
public void verifyProductArrangeInAlphaBaticalOrder() throws InterruptedException {

    List<WebElement> originalList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h2[@class='product-title']"));
    
    List<String> originalProductNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement product : originalList) {
        originalProductNameList.add(product.getText());
    }
    
    Collections.sort(originalProductNameList, Collections.reverseOrder());  // We sorted this list to descending
    System.out.println(originalProductNameList);

    // Sort by position "Name: Z to A"
    selectByVisibleTextFromDropDown(By.id("products-orderby"), "Name: Z to A");
    
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    
    waitUntilVisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h2[@class='product-title']"), 10);
    List<WebElement> afterSortingList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h2[@class='product-title']"));
    List<String> afterSortingProductName = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement product : afterSortingList) {
        afterSortingProductName.add(product.getText());
    }
    System.out.println(afterSortingProductName);

    Assert.assertEquals("Product not sorted", originalProductNameList, afterSortingProductName);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more? You are using collections to compare two lists and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: hi, Nandan Thanks for reviewing it. I would like to verify that products are in descending order once you select Z to A in the sort list. Also want to print both actual product list before sorting Z to A and after sorting Z to A.

Comment: You already sorting and comparing in your code. What else you need to do?